# Still bug in Integrate. 2

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

Let us consider in version 13.1 on Windows 10

```
a = Integrate[(-t^2 + 1)^s/((2^(-s) + t^s)*(t^2 + 1)) /. s -> 3/2, {t, 0, 1}]
```

> `4 (1/(1040 Sqrt[ 2]) \[Pi] (20 + 6 I Sqrt[3] - 11 Sqrt[3 - 2 I Sqrt[3]] -  11 Sqrt[3 + 2 I Sqrt[3]] + 5 I Sqrt[9 - 6 I Sqrt[3]] -  5 I Sqrt[9 + 6 I Sqrt[3]] +  192 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/6, 1/2, 5/6}, {4/3, 5/3},  64]) - (Gamma[-(3/4)]^2 Gamma[11/ 12] (1105 Gamma[-(5/12)] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4, 7/12, 11/12,  1}, {13/12, 17/12, 7/4}, 64] +  36 Gamma[7/ 12] (17 HypergeometricPFQ[{7/12, 11/12, 1, 5/4}, {17/12, 7/ 4, 25/12}, 64] +  448 HypergeometricPFQ[{11/12, 1, 5/4, 19/12}, {7/4, 25/12,  29/12}, 64])))/(28730 Sqrt[6 \[Pi]] Gamma[1/12] Gamma[17/12]) +  1/20475 4 Sqrt[ 2] (63 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/3, 2/3, 1, 1}, {7/6, 3/2, 11/6},  64] + 128 (9 HypergeometricPFQ[{2/3, 1, 1, 4/3}, {3/2, 11/6,  13/6}, 64] -  4 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 4/3, 5/3}, {11/6, 13/6, 5/2},  64])) - (32 Sqrt[2/(3 \[Pi])] Gamma[5/12] Gamma[3/ 4]^2 (247 Gamma[13/ 12] (3 HypergeometricPFQ[{5/12, 3/4, 1, 13/12}, {5/4, 19/12, 23/12}, 64] -  HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4, 1, 13/12, 17/12}, {19/12, 23/12, 9/ 4}, 64]) +  108 Gamma[25/ 12] HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 13/12, 17/12, 7/4}, {23/12, 9/4,  31/12}, 64]))/(144495 Gamma[19/12] Gamma[23/12]) +  1/(1040 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) 3 (Sqrt[2] MeijerG[{{1/2, 1}, {3}}, {{1/2, 1/2, 1}, {}}, 1, 2] -  32 MeijerG[{{1/2, 1}, {13/4}}, {{1/2, 3/4, 1}, {}}, 1, 2]))`

```
N[a, 15]
```

> `1.124655664721798 + 0.*10^-16 I`

and compare it with

```
NIntegrate[(-t^2 + 1)^s/((2^(-s) + t^s)*(t^2 + 1)) /. s -> 3/2, {t, 0, 1}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 20,  PrecisionGoal -> 20]
```

> `1.0230333292714399036`

The difference between the values of symbolic and numeric integration is not due to round-off errors since

```
N[4 (1/(1040 Sqrt[
  2]) \[Pi] (20 + 6 I Sqrt[3] - 11 Sqrt[3 - 2 I Sqrt[3]] - 
   11 Sqrt[3 + 2 I Sqrt[3]] + 5 I Sqrt[9 - 6 I Sqrt[3]] - 
   5 I Sqrt[9 + 6 I Sqrt[3]] + 
   192 N[HypergeometricPFQ[{1/6, 1/2, 5/6}, {4/3, 5/3}, 64], 
     15]) - (Gamma[-(3/4)]^2 Gamma[11/
    12] (1105 Gamma[-(5/12)] N[
       HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4, 7/12, 11/12, 1}, {13/12, 17/12, 7/
         4}, 64], 15] + 
     36 Gamma[7/
       12] (17 N[
          HypergeometricPFQ[{7/12, 11/12, 1, 5/4}, {17/12, 7/4, 
            25/12}, 64], 15] + 
        448 N[HypergeometricPFQ[{11/12, 1, 5/4, 19/12}, {7/4, 25/
            12, 29/12}, 64], 15])))/(28730 Sqrt[6 \[Pi]]
    Gamma[1/12] Gamma[17/12]) + 
1/20475 4 Sqrt[
 2] (63 N[
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1/3, 2/3, 1, 1}, {7/6, 3/2, 11/6}, 64], 
     15] + 128 (9 N[
        HypergeometricPFQ[{2/3, 1, 1, 4/3}, {3/2, 11/6, 13/6}, 
         64], 15] - 
      4 N[HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 4/3, 5/3}, {11/6, 13/6, 5/2}, 
         64], 15])) - (32 Sqrt[2/(3 \[Pi])]
    Gamma[5/12] Gamma[3/
    4]^2 (247 Gamma[13/
       12] (3 N[
          HypergeometricPFQ[{5/12, 3/4, 1, 13/12}, {5/4, 19/12, 
            23/12}, 64], 15] - 
        N[HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4, 1, 13/12, 17/12}, {19/12, 23/12,
            9/4}, 64], 15]) + 
     108 Gamma[25/12] N[
       HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 13/12, 17/12, 7/4}, {23/12, 9/4, 31/
         12}, 64], 15]))/(144495 Gamma[19/12] Gamma[23/12]) + 
1/(1040 Sqrt[\[Pi]])
  3 (Sqrt[2]
     N[MeijerG[{{1/2, 1}, {3}}, {{1/2, 1/2, 1}, {}}, 1, 2], 15] - 
   32 N[MeijerG[{{1/2, 1}, {13/4}}, {{1/2, 3/4, 1}, {}}, 1, 2], 
     15])), 15]
```

> `1.12465566472180+0.*10^-15 I`

Maple confirms the numeric integration result by `evalf (Int ((-t^2 + 1)^(3/2)/((2^(-3/2) + t^(3/2))*(t^2 + 1)),  t = 0 .. 1));` which performs `1.023033329`.
That bug was submitted by me in November, 2017.
Is there a workaround for the above symbolic integration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org):

```
$Version
 (**)

<< Rubi`
Z = Int[(1 - t^2)^(3/2)/((1/(2 Sqrt[2]) + t^(3/2)) (1 + t^2)), t] // Simplify

Limit[Z, t -> 1, Direction -> 1] - Limit[Z, t -> 0, Direction -> -1] // Simplify(*Some errors*)

 (*-(64/65) ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[2]] + (1/(1820 Sqrt[-3 I + 
 5 Sqrt[3]]))(-182 Sqrt[6 (-3 I + 5 Sqrt[3])] ArcTanh[2/Sqrt[3]] + 
 104 Sqrt[-7 I + 28 Sqrt[3]] ArcTanh[2/Sqrt[1/2 (9 - I Sqrt[3])]] + 
 168 Sqrt[-3 I + 12 Sqrt[3]] ArcTanh[2/Sqrt[1/2 (9 + I Sqrt[3])]] - 
 24 I Sqrt[-21 I + 84 Sqrt[3]] ArcTanh[4/Sqrt[18 - 2 I Sqrt[3]]] + 
 56 I Sqrt[-I + 4 Sqrt[3]]
 ArcTanh[4/Sqrt[18 + 2 I Sqrt[3]]] - (133 + 133 I) Sqrt[2]
 ArcTanh[(-I + Sqrt[3])/Sqrt[
 3 - 2 I Sqrt[3]]] + (875 - 875 I) Sqrt[6]
 ArcTanh[(-I + Sqrt[3])/Sqrt[
 3 - 2 I Sqrt[3]]] + (140 - 140 I) Sqrt[14]
 ArcTanh[(I + Sqrt[3])/Sqrt[
 3 + 2 I Sqrt[3]]] + (322 + 322 I) Sqrt[42]
 ArcTanh[(I + Sqrt[3])/Sqrt[3 + 2 I Sqrt[3]]]) + (1/(
 130 Sqrt[-66 + 
 30 I Sqrt[3]] (I + 
 3 Sqrt[3])))((28 Sqrt[21 (9 + I Sqrt[3])] + 
  39 Sqrt[-11 + 5 I Sqrt[3]] - 28 I Sqrt[63 + 7 I Sqrt[3]] - 
  936 Sqrt[-22 + 10 I Sqrt[3]] - 117 I Sqrt[-33 + 15 I Sqrt[3]] - 
  104 I Sqrt[-66 + 30 I Sqrt[3]] - 
  337 (-1)^(1/12) Sqrt[(-57 I - 17 Sqrt[3])/(-2 I + Sqrt[3])^2] + 
  16 I Sqrt[(-447 + 25 I Sqrt[3])/(5 I + Sqrt[3])^2] - 
  64 Sqrt[(3 (-447 + 25 I Sqrt[3]))/(5 I + Sqrt[3])^2] + 
  532 (-1)^(1/12) Sqrt[9 I + Sqrt[3]] - 
  126 (-1)^(7/12) Sqrt[3 (9 I + Sqrt[3])] + 
  269 (-1)^(7/12)
    Sqrt[-((3 (57 I + 17 Sqrt[3]))/(-2 I + Sqrt[3])^2)]) \[Pi] + 
  2 Sqrt[-22 + 
 10 I Sqrt[3]] (130 (9 + I Sqrt[3]) EllipticE[-1] - 
  98 I (-9 I + Sqrt[3]) EllipticK[-1] - 351 EllipticPi[2, -1] - 
  39 I Sqrt[3] EllipticPi[2, -1] - 
  330 EllipticPi[-1 - I Sqrt[3], -1] + 
  640 I Sqrt[3] EllipticPi[-1 - I Sqrt[3], -1] + 
  105 EllipticPi[-1 + I Sqrt[3], -1] - 
  665 I Sqrt[3] EllipticPi[-1 + I Sqrt[3], -1]))*)

 N[%, 20]
 (*1.02303332927143990355 + 0.*10^-21 I*)
```

Comment: Thank you. Not an error communication, but a warning is produced.